# SQL Case statement with logic that is a subset of existing logic

Tags: sql, if-statement, logic, case

Let's say I have a dataset as follows:

```
+----------+-------+----------+
| Customer | Price | Order ID |
+----------+-------+----------+
| john     | 4     | 1        |
| john     | 7     | 2        |
| mike     | 12    | 3        |
| mike     | 3     | 4        |
| stacy    | 3     | 5        |
| stacy    | 8     | 6        |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

I want to create a  report that gives 2 groups and their sums of prices, one for GROUP A [john + mike + stacy], another for GROUP B [john + mike].
The problem occurs when I try to write logic for a case when statement in SQL.
Because GROUP B is a subset of GROUP A, the case statement exits before it reaches the logic for GROUP B.
Say I use this code:

```
with grouped_prices as (
select
case when customer in ('john', 'mike', 'stacy') then 'GROUP A'
when customer in ('john', 'mike') then 'GROUP B'
else null end as customer_groups
, price
from mytable
)
select
customer_groups
, sum(price) as total
from grouped_prices
group by customer_groups
```

This produces the result

```
+-----------------+-------+
| customer_groups | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| GROUP A         | 37    |
+-----------------+-------+
```

But what I want is

```
+-----------------+-------+
| customer_groups | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| GROUP A         | 37    |
+-----------------+-------+
| GROUP B         | 26    |
+-----------------+-------+
```

I can achieve this solution using a UNION ALL statement, but I have to scan the table twice and this is not efficient. Is there a smarter solution than UNION ALL that I do not see?

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Just in case people are looking for language specific, but I think case statements operate in all dialects that I know of (redshift, oracle, mysql, transact...)

Comment: It's called tag spamming. Don't do it.

Comment: ah sorry, let me try to delete those language specific tags so i don't step on toes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can join to a derived table that is created on the fly as follows:

```
select sum(cp.Price) as Total, t.Group
from CustomerPrices cp
join
    (select 'Joe' as Customer, 'Group A' as Group
    union all
    select 'Sam' as Customer, 'Group A' as Group
    union all
    select 'John' as Customer, 'Group A' as Group
    union all
    select 'Joe' as Customer, 'Group B' as Group
    union all
    select 'John' as Customer, 'Group B' as Group) as t on t.Customer = cp.Customer
group by t.Group
```

Comment: Thanks dana, this is the solution I'm currently using but the union statement will be performing the table scan 2 times. Do you know of a way to implement this logic with 1 table scan?

Comment: @barker - if you had group membership defined in a different table, then you could run things in a single query (I added an example in my answer).  Also, you may consider adding an index to the `Customer` column.

Comment: thanks for the help dana, we came to the same initial conclusion. the reason i'm posting is because i wanted to see if maybe i could create a nested case statement? or any way to solve this in 1 table scan :) it's tricky, and these groups do not exists in any tables.

Comment: @barker You can use values to create them. e.g. `JOIN  (VALUES ('Group A', 'John'), ('Group A', 'Mike'), ('Group A', 'Stacy'), ('Group B', 'John'), ('Group B', 'Mike'), ('Group C', 'Mike'), ('Group C', 'Stacy'), ('Group D', 'John'), ('Group D', 'Stacy'))` etc

Comment: @ZLK - I was hunting for something like this. You should post your solution!

Comment: @barker I adjusted my query per ZLK's suggestion w/ slightly different syntax.

Comment: Thanks both ZLK/dana! Not as succinct and pretty as i'd like, but this is much faster!